# How to write client library in lua for gmail API

Tags: api, lua, gmail

I need to access gmail api using Lua.so how may i write client library to access gmail api in Lua

Answer (score 1):

In order to write a library for any API - you need to have a way to perform HTTP requests.

You can either use a Lua extension library such as this one:
https://github.com/daurnimator/lua-http

Or if you are fluent in C++ - create your own.